# Replacing column values of dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 both of same column numbers.
I want to replace all the column values of df1 with corresponding first row value from df2 columns.

```
df1$col1<-df2$col1[1]
.
.
.
df1$col17<-df2$col17[1]
```

Is there a better way of doing this?
Please suggest the way forward.

Comment: try a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could directly assign the values by using `[]`

```
df1[] <- df2[1, ]
df1
#  col1 col2 col3
#1    1    2    5
#2    1    2    5
#3    1    2    5
#4    1    2    5
#5    1    2    5
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 2:6, col3 = 3:7)
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 2:4, col3 = 5:7)
```